# How to disable Ubuntu launcher tooltip text?

Tags: unity, launcher, tooltip

The tooltip text (hover) in the Unity launcher obscures my window previews and is rather unnecessary in general. Is there a way to disable it?

[image]

Comment: That seems odd. The tooltip should disappear once your mouse cursor leaves it.

Comment: @edwinksl I updated the image, it doesn't stay when I don't hover. I'm talking about the window preview.